# dd Copies Drive with no Errors, Gparted shows Partitions as Empty, No Flags

Tags: backup, partitioning, gparted, dd, partition-copy

So with the assistance of Hennes I was able to use `dd` to copy my entire sda to sdb, but after dd finished I checked the partitions with `gparted` and found that all partitions were listed as empty, the boot flag was missing, and all listed as unmounted, so I was wondering if anybody knew what went wrong, I checked the information and have the same error on all partitions:

> Warning, the device /dev/sdb2 doesn't exist. ntfsresize v2oo12.1.15ar.1 (libntfs-3g) error(2):failed to check '/dev/sdb2' mount state no such file or directory Probably /etc/mtab is missing. It's too risky to continue. You might try an another linux distro. Unable to read the contents of this file system! Because of this some operations may be unavailable. The cause might be a missing software package. The following list of software packages is required for ntfs file system support : ntfsprogs / ntfs-3g

Comment: Do you have ntfs-3g or ntfsprogs installed? (looks so, but just to check)

Comment: I'm pretty sure dd is *not* the right way to copy disks. Disks aren't so simple to copy - they contain MBR, etc. dd is simply a dumb byte copier

Comment: Honestly, right now I'm not sure, I've been at this for 14 hours, it's the gparted live disc so I assume it comes with it, we copied it with dd in ubuntu earlier but ran into a error with ubuntu and it only copied 2 of the 3 partitions.

Comment: please review chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access  , dd works.